How to make GN group's input default value available for asset use?
I found that GN group input default values are not given when using the group as asset in another project. How should I solve this?
Example:
The follow is a simple GN group that scales mesh size. The default value for the input "scale" is set to 1.

I marked this group as asset

Now, using this file as asset in another project, shows default 0.0 and not 1.0 :/


Did you try pressing Backspace while hovering the Scale field ? Default shortcut to set to default value.

@Lutzi - it sets the value to 0, not the default value I made in the asset project
